# Passing arrays as return type inside if condition

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to have an array as the return type inside an if condition in a "Set Variable" activity in Azure Data Factory. As the hint suggests in the screenshot, the if condition has a signature of `if(boolean, any, any):any` but when I pass `if(boolean, array, array)` it seems to not accept this, and throws an "Invalid" error-like message. I cannot save this ADF pipeline.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Screenshot showing the if condition's signature and the error complaining about using an array which should be a subclass of any:

[image: Screenshot showing the if condition's signature and the error complaining about using an array which should be a subclass of any]

Answer (score 0):

Create an **array** variable to store the return value from the `Set variable` activity based on the boolean expression evaluated (true or false).

I have reproed with the sample values by creating 2 array variables for the return values of the **IF** function based on true or false, and an array variable to store the return value.

**Variables:**

[image]

**Set variable activity:**

Expression: `@if(equals(1,1),variables('array1') , variables('array2'))`

[image]

**Result:**

[image]